# How to find intersection of two list of dictionaries in Python 3?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

i've found similar, almost same questions but none of these helped me. 
For example, if i have two lists:

```
list1 = [{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3},{'a':1, 'b':5, 'c':6}]
list2 = [{'a':2,'b':4,'c':9},{'a':1, 'b':4, 'c':139}]
```

You can see that in first list all dicts have same 'a' and in second the key 'b' is same in all dicts in list. I want to find a dictionary which has the key 'a' from first list and key 'b' from second list but only if that dictionary is inside one of these lists (in this example, it would be [{'a':1, 'b':4, 'c':139}]). Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: what is the condition for c:139 to come in output? I can see it is not repeating in either of the list.

Comment: It's just random number

Comment: so `[{'a':1, 'b':4, 'c':149}]` would be a valid output for your question?

Answer (score 0):

Not particularly attractive, but does the trick.

```
list1 = [{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3},{'a':1, 'b':5, 'c':6}]
list2 = [{'a':2,'b':4,'c':9},{'a':1, 'b':4, 'c':139}]

newdict = {} #the dictionary with appropriate 'a' and 'b' values that you will then search for

#get 'a' value
if list1[0]['a']==list1[1]['a']:
    newdict['a'] = list1[0]['a']
#get 'b' value
if list2[0]['b']==list2[1]['b']:
    newdict['b'] = list2[0]['b']

#just in case 'a' and 'b' are not in list1 and list2, respectively
if len(newdict)!=2:
    return

#find if a dictionary that matches newdict in list1 or list2, if it exists
for dict in list1+list2:
    matches = True #assume the dictionaries 'a' and 'b' values match

    for item in newdict: #run through 'a' and 'b'
        if item not in dict:
            matches = False
        else:
            if dict[item]!=newdict[item]:
                matches = False
    if matches:
        print(dict)
        return
```

Comment: You are genius bro... Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

This solution works with any keys:

```
def key_same_in_all_dict(dict_list):
    same_value = None
    same_value_key = None
    for key, value in dict_list[0].items():
        if all(d[key] == value for d in dict_list):
            same_value = value
            same_value_key = key
            break
    return same_value, same_value_key

list1 = [{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3},{'a':1, 'b':5, 'c':6}]
list2 = [{'a':2,'b':4,'c':9},{'a':1, 'b':4, 'c':139}]

list1value, list1key = key_same_in_all_dict(list1)
list2value, list2key = key_same_in_all_dict(list2)

for dictionary in list1 + list2:
    if list1key in dictionary and dictionary[list1key] == list1value and list2key in dictionary and dictionary[list2key] == list2value:
            print(dictionary)
```

Prints `{'a': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 139}`

Answer (score 0):

This maybe:

```
your_a = list1[0]['a'] # will give 1
your_b = list2[0]['b'] # will give 4

answer = next((x for x in list1 + list2 if x['a'] == your_a and x['b'] == your_b), None)
```